# What is the use of -r in the pip install command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

What is the use of -r in this install command?

```
pip install -r requirments.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the [manpage of **`pip`** [manpages]](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/python-pip/pip.1), we see:

> ```
> -r,--requirement <file>
>        Install from the given requirements file.  This  option  can  be
>        used multiple times.
> ```

It thus means that we specify a file that contains the requirements. You can use it multiple times, for example:

```
pip install -r requirements1.txt -r requirements2.txt
```